# NodeJS script on Docker: /lib64/libz.so.1: version `ZLIB_1.2.9' not found

Tags: node.js, windows, docker, docker-for-windows, sharp

I use sharp library for my image processing in the node js script which in turn is running my test cases using jest-image-snapshot.

I have got this error

**/lib64/libz.so.1: version `ZLIB_1.2.9' not found**

Found similar issue on [NodeJS app on OpenShift: /lib64/libz.so.1: version `ZLIB_1.2.9' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51122526/nodejs-app-on-openshift-lib64-libz-so-1-version-zlib-1-2-9-not-found/51259103#51259103) 
and tried preloading the dependency.

But then, I have got error on preloading as well

**ERROR: ld.so: object '/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/sharp/vendor/lib/libz.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.**

Please help to resolve this..

I have been trying this in my Windows OS

NOTE: The same script works fine in a mac OS

Comment: What is in your LD_LIBRARY_PRELOAD?

Comment: "scripts": {
    "test": "LD_PRELOAD='./node_modules/sharp/vendor/lib/libz.so' node testRunner"
  },

Comment: I meant LD_PRELOAD environment variable (i.e. echo $LD_PRELOAD or env | grep LD_PRELOAD)

If it is set to something, try to unset it, then run again npm install.

You can get an interactive bash session on your docker container.